# Difference between the char and int in C#

Tags: c#, char, int

Creating a C# program to prompt the user to choose the correct answer from a list of answer choices of a question and if the answer is wrong then try to prompt the same question again with do while loop but it is not working as it suppose to be.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       char UserChoice = ' ';
       do
       {
               Console.WriteLine("What is the command keyword to exit a loop in C#?");
               Console.WriteLine("a.quit");
               Console.WriteLine("b.continue");
               Console.WriteLine("c.break");
               Console.WriteLine("d.exit");
               UserChoice = ' ';
               Console.WriteLine("Please enter a b c or d");
               UserChoice = (char)Console.Read();
               switch (UserChoice)
               {
                   case 'a': Console.WriteLine("wrong ans"); break;
                   case 'b': Console.WriteLine("wrong ans"); break;
                   case 'd': Console.WriteLine("wrong ans"); break;
                   case 'c': Console.WriteLine("right"); break;
                   default: Console.WriteLine("Bad choice {0}", UserChoice); break;
               }
       } while (UserChoice == 'a' || UserChoice == 'b' || UserChoice == 'd');
    }
}
```

but if i use int instead of char in this program and replace a, b, c and d with 1, 2, 3 and 4 then this program work fine. Please some one can explain it what  is wrong in this code when using char.

Comment: what happens when you use char? You get error? if so, what is the error?

Comment: @adv12 His code seems to be correct with respect to that point.  a,b,c and d aren't commands, they're guesses as to the meaning of a command.  Read the text of the question being asked.

Comment: @Servy, yup that was me skimming.  Thanks.

Comment: So when I run the program by using char -- choose wrong answer then it prompt me the same question again and picked up the bad choice answer which is default one itself. This is where the program is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read in a single character you should use `Console.ReadKey`.

`Console.Read` waits for input from the console, which means reading in an entire line in most shells, and then gives you the ASCII value of the first character of that input as an `int`.

If you just use `ReadKey` you can get an actual `char` representing the next character pressed, and don't need to worry about how to convert what you get into a `char`.

Comment: It doesn't let me use char UserChoice = Console.Readkey(); as error says --> can't implicit convert type System.Consolekeyinfo to char.

Comment: I have used ConsolekeyInfo UserChoice = Console.ReadKey(); and then use UserChoice.keyChar to use where ever require in the code.